Who was R. Hanina of Rome?
Rashbam to Bava Batra 30a (s.v. mi lo amrinan) quotes an halakhic ruling from "the Commentaries of R. Hanina of Rome".
Do we know who this R. Hanina is, and what work Rashbam is quoting from?

This forum here https://forum.otzar.org/viewtopic.php?t=9286 questions if it is a printing mistake.

ברש"י יומא כט: כותב: ולי נראה דלא גרסינן פסולה ... והכי נמי גרסינן בפי' הר"ח איש רומי...
והכונה שם לפי' רבנו חננאל כמו שיראה המעיין בפי' הר"ח אלא שמגיהי דפוס וילנא, לא עיינו ברש"י שבאותו עמוד, והוסיפו בפנים הר"ח בסוגריים מרובעות [פסולה], וכבר העירו שם בהוצאת עו"ה שטעות בידם.
אגב בטקסט שבבר אילן (שבמסכת זו מקורו ממהדו' שטיינזלץ) פתחו בטעות ר' חנינא איש רומי, וכמו שמופיע בדפוסים בטעות ברשב"ם בב"ב (דף ל.) ושם הגיה הרש"ש (כמובא בהגו"צ של עו"ה) שצ"ל רבנו חננאל איש רומי, וכן הוא בדפוסי לובלין וונציה, וכן מופיע במפורש גם לפנינו להלן בפי' הרשב"ם (דף פו:).

ואין לומר שהרש"י הנ"ל ביומא הוא הגה"ה שהרי מוקף בסוגריים מרובעות, כי הביאו שם בהגו"צ של עו"ה שקטע זה הוא מרש"י ישן שהביאו הראשונים והמהרש"א

Thanks @Dov.... looks like you may have the basis of an answer here
